# 404 not found after manual installation of marketplace

Tags: 404-page

I installed **multivendor marketplace** manually in my magento site. Everything seems to be working fine in frontend such as user is able to register as seller, add products, edit products etc.

But, while clicking on any of the sub menus under **Marketplace tab** in the **admin panel** then it redirects to **404 Not Found page** except **configuration** which is working fine.

If someone has faced issue like this then please help me to resolve this.

I am using magento 1.9.0.1.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you applied the 6788 security patch? This patch affects admin routes and could result in the symptoms you have. Potentially the extension hasn't been updated to be compatible with the patch. As its a third party extension and not core Magento, you will probably be better off going to the extension developer for this.

If it is just a blank admin screen then you might just need to log out and log back in again so the correct permissions can be loaded.

Comment: andrewkett : thanks for the comment, **patch 6788** is not applied on my site as earlier when i tried to apply it then it gave me errors by breaking various parts of website. But until now everything has worked fine except when I integrated **Marketplace manually**.

Comment: I can successfully login to the admin panel but 404 Not Found only comes when I try to access marketplace.

Comment: @kanand304 have you got the success ?